# How to use wildcard in excel vba internet explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, wildcard

could you please tell me how to use wildcards in excel vba internet explorer?

```
id="btn_edit_card_1NLQNQD0D93O"
```

everytime that number in different. How to click that button via

```
 document.getElementById
```

There is no class in code

```
 <a id="btn_edit_card_1NLQNQD0D93O" href="/trades/bejelentes_egyszerusitett/1NLQNQD0D93O">Editing basic data</a>
```

Comment: Probably this `document.getElementById` is a part of a collection. Try to refer the collection and try to get the first element from it.

Comment: @Vityata i do not understand, I want to click that button via objIE.document.getElementById("btn_edit_card_????????????").Click but I have no idea how to use wildcard to click it

Comment: you could use `.getElementsByTagName("a")` and then iterate this collection until it's `like 'btn_edit_card_*'`  Look at the proper libraries also, this will help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703928(v=vs.85).aspx   and this  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Nathan_Sav suggested, very wisely I might add, that you will have to work around your problem with collections.  For example, loop through all the "a" tags until you find one that   "btn_edit_card_" as part of it's name.  This will work unless there are more than one "a" tags with that phrase in it.

```
    Set els = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each el In els
         If el.ID Like "btn_edit_card*" 
            el.click
            Exit For
'           Debug.Print el.ID, el.Name
         End If  
    Next el
```

Answer (score 2):

If your IE version is 9 or above you can use the `querySelectorAll` method of the `HTMLDocument` class.

This uses [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to enable filtering of elements by their attributes. In your case you are looking for `a` elements with an `id` beginning with `btn_edit_card`. The selector for this would be:

`a[^=btn_edit_card]`

Where the `^=` means *begins with*.

See the example code below that pulls comments from this very page - they are all `tr` elements in a table beneath your question which all have `id` of `comment-123456` where the number can change from comment to comment (because they are stored uniquely in the database etc):

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetElementByWildcard()

    Dim objIe As InternetExplorer
    Dim objDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim objElements As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    On Error GoTo ExitFunction

    'get page content
    Set objIe = New InternetExplorer
    objIe.Visible = False
    objIe.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225761/how-to-use-wildcard-in-excel-vba-internet-explorer"
    Do While objIe.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    'get document
    Set objDoc = objIe.document

    'get any <tr> with an id starting with comment-
    Set objElements = objDoc.querySelectorAll("tr[id^=comment-]")

    'iterate output
    lngCounter = 0
    While lngCounter < objElements.Length
        Set objElement = objElements.Item(lngCounter)
        Debug.Print objElement.innerText
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    Wend

ExitFunction:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Description
    End If

    objIe.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objIe = Nothing


End Sub
```